# Is there a recommended replacement for Team Explorer Everywhere for Eclipse / Java Development?

Tags: java, eclipse, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

The documentation I could find indicates that TEE is still the recommended way of integrating Azure DevOps Repos / TFVC with Eclipse (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=azure-devops)

However it does not support more current versions of Eclipse and the github page for TEE (https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere) shows that the project is no longer maintained.

So how are Azure DevOps users doing Java development expected to proceed as Eclipse continues updating but the TEE plugin does not?

Comment: Not sure how much better of an option it is but I've found that the Azure DevOps plugin for IntelliJ is more stable :( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/download-intellij-plug-in?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi,Dale,I gave a replacement for TEE,does my answer help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If developers do not want to use Microsoft's Team Explorer Everywhere
>   plug-in for Eclipse, they can choose to use eGit to connect to TFS.

This is listed in this [document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server#cite_note-15) , I think you can try use [eGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) as a replacement for TEE.

In addition ,at the moment, the TEE plugin is just no longer maintained. You can still use that, or you can create the branch then commit some changes into it, thus you can still use this plugin.

As the git hub stated :

> To make changes, you may fork this repository and build your own
>   version of Team Explorer Everywhere using instructions below.

So you can also continue to use TEE by building your own version.

Comment: I should have been more clear that our organization uses TFVC for version control, not Git, but this answer is basically the same as the official support response from MS so I'l mark it.