# MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error Cannot complete request to https://marketplace

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Version: Neon (4.6)Build id: I20160606-1100
When I launch eclipse and try to go to Marketplace via Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, I am getting the following error and hence unable to connect to marketplace server to download any plugins.

Here is the error.

MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=en_US&java.version=1.8.0_181&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.6.0.I20160606-1100&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.0.v20160606-1100: Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=en_US&java.version=1.8.0_181&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.6.0.I20160606-1100&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.0.v20160606-1100.

Can some help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is more than 12 releases behind and more than 4 years old. Please upgrade.

Comment: I am using Neon because I need to connect to   "Team Explorer Everywhere" to connect Eclipse to Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server. Team Explorer Everywhere plug-in works with Eclipse versions 4.2 (Juno) - 4.6 (Neon).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001328/

Comment: Note that the MSFT person who answered the above advised forking and building if you want to use the Team Explorer Everywhere plugin with a more recent version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know why that is happening.  I can think of a couple of *possible* reasons:

- It could have been a transient problem with the Marketplace server / service.  I was able to load the URL in your question (in a web browser), so if that was the problem, it appears to have been resolved.
- It could be a firewall and/or proxy configuration problem at your end:

  - Can you load the URL in a web browser?
  - Can you `curl` or `wget` it?
  - Have you configured the network proxy settings in Eclipse.  See [How do I have to configure the proxy settings so Eclipse can download new plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499)

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your reply. I am able to access the url from my browser. And curl is giving me the following response.

Comment: curl https://sede-ds-adp.visualstudio.com/
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodweu1.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=sede-ds-adp.visualstudio.com&amp;reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsede-ds-adp.visualstudio.com%2F&amp;redirect=1&amp;hid=1c29edfb-c2b4-4b9d-bcfc-07cad5999522&amp;context=eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiMWM0M2Y0MTQtNmNhYS00YmVkLTgyYzQtMjQ1M2MwMDFiMmFmIiwicXMiOnt9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90#ctx=eyJTaWduSW5Db29raWVEb21haW5zIjpbImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSIsImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLm

Comment: That's OK.  Eclipse should be able to cope with a redirect.  Now check the Eclipse network proxy settings.

Comment: There was no proxy defined in eclipse settings. I added one with port number as 8080. Still the issue persists.

Comment: Why are you using port 8080?  Does your proxy server use port 8080?  You should use the same port as your proxy server uses.